# Status of the wavefunction in QM after QFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, wavefunction

In QFT which is the continuation of QM the Quantum fields are considered as the final objective reality. If this is true why is there not a last and deceisive Interpretation of the wavefunction, which must be an artifact of the fields?

Comment: QFT has a wavefunction. It just doesn't have a position-basis wavefunction that has good particle number.

Comment: You can write a wave function[al] in quantum field theory, but the theory does not have the kind of clean probabilistic interpretation as in nonrelativistic quantum mechanics.  Only in certain limits are the probability amplitudes well defined.

Comment: @Buzz if you take a Wightman QFT, it admits the probabilistic interpretation pretty much by definition. Do you mean perturbative QFT where only the scattering matrix can be given such an interpretation? It isn't clear to me whether this is a feature of reality, or an artifact of faulty approximation methods (asymptotic expansion).

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov One part of it is what you say—that only the $S$-matrix has a probabilistic interpretation in perturbation theory.  You can use Wightman functions, but their relationship to physical observables is tenuous at best in an interacting theory in 3+1 dimensions.

Comment: @Buzz what do you mean by “relationship with physical observables”?

Answer (score 4):

Interpretations don't disagree on what counts as a wavefunction. In fact, all interpretations of QM deal with the same projective Hilbert space, elements of which are none other than wavefunctions.

Interpretations disagree on how to, well, interpret wavefunctions. Specifically, it is the probabilistic predictions of quantum mechanics (the Born rule) which are logically interpreted differently.

Everything is exactly the same in QFT. QFT also has a Hilbert space of "wavefunctions" and operators that correspond to physical observables. For example, consider the state
$$ \left| \Psi \right> = \left( c_0 + a_p^{\dagger} c_1 \right) \left| 0 \right>. $$

Say you want to measure the number of particles in the field. The Born rule tells you that you will get 0 particles with probability $|c_0|^2$ and 1 particle with probability $|c_1|^2$ (assuming the coefficients and the states are normalized properly).

As far as the math is concerned, you've measured the state and you're done. The probabilities are all there is to know.

Now it's up to the interpretation to "make sense" of this unambiguous prediction. What happens during/after the measurement? Does the state collapse? If so, what happened to particle number / energy conservation? Are states/particles/fields real? Am I real?

Comment: Here comes the problem with collapse of wavefunction. As a amplitude of the probabiliy it can vanish after a measurent. But quantum fields as considered real can not do this. An excitation of the field (e.g. a particle) should spread as a sphere in space. After been measured in point B it must disappear (at least return to vacuum state which is not the same as 1 particle state).

Comment: @Mercury I'm not sure what you mean by "quantum fields (as considered real)". A quantum field according to my definition is an operator-valued distribution. I.e. it is a linear functional from test functions on space-time to operators on the Hilbert space. This is called Wightman axioms for quantum field theory. So a quantum field is nothing more than a physical observable, an operator (defined for any test function). Just like $x$ and $p$ are operators in quantum mechanics.

Comment: For me the field would be real if it does not disappear in p.B immediately with measurement in p.C. An excitation of the field (meaning the operator of the field varies with time) created in p.A travels to both C and B which are space-like separated. Then the operator will be different from identity operator in C and B. But when one measures in C then the operator would collapse to identity in B.

Comment: This can not be done by a real thing. So does only the probabilistic wavefunction. This means to me that operator fields are a math construct on the same level as the wavefunction. But there are physicists (like David Tong) who insist that fields are real as an underlying basis of the world

Comment: @Mercury operators don't travel anywhere, they are defined once and for all, statically, for all spacetime points simply by the dynamics of the quantum field theory. There are also no excitations (especially in the value of the operator density field) traveling from point a to point b, that is just a semiclassical analogy and nothing more. The physics is encoded in the vacuum expectation values of products of operators taken at different spacetime points – these are called Wightman functions.

Comment: @Mercury your comments make me doubt that you've taken the quantum field theory course. Maybe postpone the interpretational questions until you're fluent in QFT?

Comment: How is then the travelling of a free electron represented? You are right in the few books I read on QFT I never encountered a clear picture of this. I can assure you am very well familiar with the mathematics of QFT. You have some books where the physics is presented?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102632/discussion-between-prof-legolasov-and-mercury).